# Add text from textarea as text when share using custom facebook share button

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, share

I've made custom facebook share button. I have textarea field and I want when user writes some text in it and click on Share button, image to be shared with text from this textarea. I've made this to work except for text from textarea. I haven't added text from it when sharing. Is there a way to do that?

My code is:

```html
<textarea cols="134" rows="3" name="share_text">
</textarea>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo URL::base();?>image/1234">
   <input class="btn col-md-2" type="button" value="Share" />
 </a>
```

Comment: Not possible using the dialogs. You would need to make the post via API.

Comment: Could you give some idea how to do it? Maybe no need to show facebook share dialog, when user writes some text and click Share -> to share on facebook directly.

Comment: Or maybe no need to provide a textarea on your page, when the user can input their message directly via the interface the Share dialog provides …? And if you want to know how posting via API works, then go read up on that in the docs/research it first please.